# Doctrine entity created in a working zf2 module does not update the database

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I ve created a new module in zf2 to store some entities and their apis. The module is configured and working since I can access the declared api routes. When I contact the api it is sending me an error because the table does not exist.

But when I run `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` or `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force` I received this output :

`Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.`

Which is not true since my table is not created in the database.

My module config :

```
namespace Enrollment;

return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'iaFileSetApi' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/api/ia-file-sets[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Enrollment\Controller\IAFileSetRest',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Enrollment\Controller\IAFileSetRest' => 'Enrollment\Controller\IAFileSetRestController'
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view'
    ),
),
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver')
        )
    )
),);
```

My Entity :

```
<?php
namespace Enrollment\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ia_file_sets")
 */
class IAFileSet{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false)
 */
protected $name;


public function toArray()
{
    return [
        "id" => $this->getId(),
        "name" => $this->getName(),
    ];
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was a new module, I deleted the autoloader cache files and now my entities sync correctly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Where are the autoloader cache files located at?